# Sort Numbers & Text Separated by Comma in Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a combination of text and numbers.  It works for the sorting, but where the cell is correct, it gives me an #VALUE! error.  It also does not populate when it's a single value example PR54.  How do I correct this?

Original cell:
A1, B13, B15

Result receiving:
#VALUE!

Desired result:
A1, B13, B15

```vb
Function StrSort(ByVal sInp As String, _
                 Optional bDescending As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim asSS()  As String 
    Dim sSS     As String
    Dim n       As Long
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim j       As Long

    asSS = Split(sInp, ",")
    n = UBound(asSS)

 
    Dim TemporaryNumberArray() As Double

    For i = 0 To n
        If IsNumeric(Trim(asSS(i))) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            If IsError(UBound(TemporaryNumberArray)) Then
                ReDim TemporaryNumberArray(0 To 0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve TemporaryNumberArray(0 To UBound(TemporaryNumberArray) + 1)
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            TemporaryNumberArray(UBound(TemporaryNumberArray)) = asSS(i)
        End If
     Next
 
    n = UBound(TemporaryNumberArray) 
    If n < 1 Then
        StrSort = sInp
    Else
        For i = 0 To n - 1
            For j = i + 1 To n
                If (TemporaryNumberArray(j) < TemporaryNumberArray(i)) Xor bDescending Then
                    sSS = TemporaryNumberArray(i)
                    TemporaryNumberArray(i) = TemporaryNumberArray(j)
                    TemporaryNumberArray(j) = sSS
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
 
        StrSort = CStr(TemporaryNumberArray(0))
        For i = 1 To n
            StrSort = StrSort & ", " & CStr(TemporaryNumberArray(i))
        Next
    End If
 
    If n < UBound(asSS) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(asSS)
            If Not IsNumeric(asSS(i)) Then
                StrSort = StrSort & ", " & asSS(i)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Function
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't post code where every line is double- or triple-spaced. It requires a lot of scrolling, which makes your code difficult to review....   If you need to debug a UDF which you're calling from a worksheet cell, try calling it from a VBA Sub instead - you can then see any errors and fix them

Comment: "A1, B13, B15" - none of these are numeric?  It's not really how you want to sort these values.

Comment: `n = UBound(TemporaryNumberArray)` will raise a run-time error if none of the values in the split array are numeric (ie. when you have not assigned a UBound to `TemporaryNumberArray`)

Comment: Is there anything in the macro I can do for the order of the non-numeric values?

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what you want to do when sorting - some example inputs and expected outputs would be useful here.

Comment: The goal of the macro is to take a string of data that is either just numeric, alpha, or a combination of both numeric and alpha and put it into chronological order.  The macro I created does not do that.  It throws #value errors with the combined values.

Comment: What does "chronological order" mean here?  These are not dates or times?  Again, please provide some sample inputs and expected outputs.  I'm not sure we can fix your code without knowing what it's *supposed* to do.

Comment: The original string is mixed values- N807, MA01, MA15, 18.  The goal is to have them in order: 18, N807, MA01, MA15.  Also, for the macro to work and not throw a #VALUE! when the values are like N807, MA01, MA07.  Instead, put these in order which is the same as the original string.

Comment: What are *the rules for sorting* though?  Why does "N807, MA01, MA15, 18" become "18, N807, MA01, MA15"

Comment: "N807, MA01, MA15" is not alphabetic sorting, unless you mean descending?

Comment: First, it must sort the numbers. Then the alphanumeric.  In alphabetic order.  These medical denial codes that insurance carriers put on their claims.  We are trying to group them together per claim in order of smallest to highest 1 to ZZ999.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. You can call `SortList` from a worksheet and it will return the sorted list.

```vb
Function SortList(c) As String
    Dim arr, i
    
    arr = Split(c, ",")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'trim all array elements
        arr(i) = Trim(arr(i))
    Next i
    SortArray arr                'sort in-place
    SortList = Join(arr, ",")  'return sorted
End Function

'Sort an array in-place
Sub SortArray(list)
    Dim First As Long, Last As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmp
    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If DoCompare(Trim(list(i)), Trim(list(j))) Then 'compare the values
                tmp = list(j)             '...and in the original array
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

'Compare two values and return true if `a` is greater than `b`
'  (numeric values are sorted first)
Function DoCompare(a, b) As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(a) And IsNumeric(b) Then
        DoCompare = CDbl(a) > CDbl(b) 'two numbers
    ElseIf IsNumeric(a) Or IsNumeric(b) Then
        DoCompare = IsNumeric(b)      'one numeric, one alpha
    Else
        DoCompare = a > b             'two alphas
    End If
End Function
```